# Limesurvey saved surveys not getting assigned to correct user id

Tags: limesurvey

I have a weird problem on my lime survey installation.

People save their half filed surveys for submission later. When they login at a later time to resume their forms, they get someone else's half filled form. This is causing a problem for my survey applicants. Much of the survey information collected is supposed to remain private.

I've just started to look into the code to see why this is happening. However, if someone has faced a similar problem and knows how to solve please do let me know.

**Update 1:**

> I found the table which maps surveys to saved user logins its
>   called the [tableprefix]_saved_control.

**Update 2:**

> I have found out by some algorithm that only 2 logins are
>   affected.. It was probably more before.

P.S I'm not sure whether the question meets the S.O guidelines but I'm happy to change it depending on what is wrong.

Comment: Strange issue, LimeSurvey version please ? If it's not the last : update it.

Comment: The username are the same ?

Comment: Yes.. authentications works. Just the wrong record is fetched. .

Comment: You mean user take same name for save their answers ?

Comment: I have the same problem with an open survey allowing "resume later". My LS is Version 2.06+ Build 160129. Is there a solution or explanation? I have not found.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe linked with this : https://github.com/Shnoulle/LimeSurvey-shnoulle/commit/a6462bb2934c4b3fc1d83daaf1119636db47d25f

Conclusion : always better to report a bug for Free Tools.